# Twilio API; SMS not sending

Tags: java, twilio

I need help with this class, its not even returning the SIDs of the messages. My application is meant to be ran 24/7 and it sends messages when it first begins, but then it shortly fails to send messages. Do I need to remake the TwilioRestClient object each time a message is sent?

```
public class Twilio {

public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "VALID SID";
public static final String ACCOUNT_AUTH = "VALID AUTH";

private static Twilio instance;

public static Twilio getInstance() {
    return instance == null ? (instance = new Twilio()) : instance;
}

private TwilioRestClient client;
private SmsFactory smsFactory;

private Map<String, String> defaultProps = new HashMap<>();

public Twilio() {
    defaultProps.put("From", "VALID TWILIO NUMBER");
    client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, ACCOUNT_AUTH);
}

public SmsFactory getSMSFactory() {
    return smsFactory == null ? (smsFactory = client.getAccount().getSmsFactory()) : smsFactory;
}

private Sms buildSMS(String recipient, String body) {
    Sms sms = null;
    defaultProps.put("To", recipient);
    defaultProps.put("Body", body);
    try {
        sms = getSMSFactory().create(defaultProps);
    } catch (TwilioRestException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    return sms;
}

public String[] sendSMS(String body, String... recipients) {
    List<String> sids = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String r : recipients)
        sids.add(buildSMS(r, body).getSid());
    return sids.toArray(new String[sids.size()]);
}
```

}

Comment: When you say "fails to send messages" can you be more clear?

Comment: It's not even logging it as sent messages on the website log pane. Its like its not even making the request.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code if it helps. its working fine for me.

```
public boolean sendSMS(String to, String from, String text){
    try {
        String[] toarr = to.split(",");
        TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN); 
        if(toarr.length > 0){
            for (int i = 0; i < toarr.length; i++) {
               List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", toarr[i]));
               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", from)); 
               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body", text));
               MessageFactory messageFactory = client.getAccount().getMessageFactory(); 
               com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.Message message = messageFactory.create(params); 
            }
        }
   }
    catch (TwilioRestException tex) {
        tex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}
```